# ProFTPd and www-data group

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd, webmin

What I'm trying to do is create a ftp user that can update and modify files in an apache2 v2.4 (with www-data) web directory.

I have a single user: UserA (names changed to protect the guilty)
The folder is /var/www/vhosts; chowned to www-data:www-data
UserA has been addded to the www-data group.
The UserA's home directory is set to /var/www/vhosts

I have ProFTPd setup and running. 
UserA connects fine.

The problem is ownership of the folders/files.
all files are set to 644 as normal
all folders are set to 755.

since UserA is not the owner, it falls under the group policies and files cannot be added, deleted, or modified because of the limitations.

Is there any way to masquerade UserA as www-data so they can perform the job?

Am I thinking of this the right way?  is there another way to do it?
Thanks
The user connects via FTP to the web folder

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you would like to FTP into your web server and upload files to the webroot. The owner and group of the files (and directories?) are `www-data:www-data`.

What may paritally be happening (been a while since I used ProFTP) is the `umask` of userA is configured in ProFTP with a differnt `umask` than what the shell uses.  This can make troubleshooting confusing.

I would try the following:

- add `userA` to the `www-data` group (as you have done)
- assign mode `0775` to the `vhosts` directory (eg: `chmod 0775`)
- apply SGID (eg: `chmod g+w+s vhosts`) on `vhosts` so any files there have group perms applied

This should accomplish:

- userA uploads a file which lands in `vhosts` owned by `userA` but with `www-data` group ownership
- since the `vhosts` directory does not have the sticky bit set (set above to `0775`) any user in the `www-data` group with group-write access to `vhosts` can delete/modify the file

**NOTE**: pay particular attention to `apparmor` and possibly `SElinux`. You may need to adjust configuration of those utilities (if installed) to allow the webserver or ProtFTP to write there.

**NOTE**: For a recommended,secure alternative to FTP, look into WinSCP/SFTP. By generating a OpenSSH key pair, you can drop your public key in the `www-data` user's home directory and "masquerade" as the web server when you login over WinSCP. This allows for encrypted communication, more secure authentication, and less rigamarole with the permission twiddling.